# Weird Compile Error using Pthreads

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, posix

i am using LINUX 10.04 i think this is not a problem,anyway i have a 
Weird Error.
To me all looks perfect.
So what is the problem?
Sorry for this format type.i am new here.

```
   //COMPILE with:  gcc -g -Wall -pthread pthread_ex_book_pg193.c -lpthread -o MYthread  

/* the program is simple.We create two threads One is for the main () and th esecond with the pthread_create().
The second thread calls a function runner()  to calculate a sum and when it finishes it    returns to the main thread */


#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int sum;
void *runner(void *argv[]);
int  main (int argc,char *argv[]){
pthread_t tid; //thread id 
pthread_attr_t attr;//thread attributes
if (argc!=2){
fprintf(stderr,"usage: a.out<integer value> \n");
return -1;
}
if (atoi(argv[1]) < 0){
fprintf(stderr, "%d must be >=0\n ",atoi(argv[1]));
return -1;
}
pthread_attr_init(&attr);
pthread_create(&tid,&attr,runner,argv[1]);
pthread_join(tid,NULL);
printf("sum = %d \n",sum);
}

void *runner(void *param){
int i;
int upper = atoi(param); 
sum=0;
for (i=1;i<=upper;i++){
sum=sum+i;
pthread_exit(0);
}
}
```

Comment: What is the exact text of the compiler error?  At a guess, is it about your forward declaration of `runner`?  It should be `void *runner(void *arg);`

Comment: SO is not a code review site. Try to formulate a concrete question about what you don't understand. Error messages are important, they provide information, read them, share them.

Comment: GCC printed that:


pthread_ex_book_pg193.c: In function ‘main’:
pthread_ex_book_pg193.c:25: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘pthread_create’ from incompatible pointer type
/usr/include/pthread.h:225: note: expected ‘void * (*)(void *)’ but argument is of type ‘void * (*)(void **)’
pthread_ex_book_pg193.c: At top level:
pthread_ex_book_pg193.c:30: error: conflicting types for ‘runner’
pthread_ex_book_pg193.c:12: note: previous declaration of ‘runner’ was here
nkbaroutis@nkbaroutis-VGN-FW11M:~/Cscripts/threads$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
void *runner(void *argv[]);
```

to

```
void *runner(void *argv);
```

(1) Your forward declaration of runner clashes with your later usage; (2) the proper signature of a thread's start function is `void* f(void*)` - IOW it takes a single pointer to void not an array of pointers to void.